# Listening to multiple groups simultaneously in SignalR

Tags: signalr

We're working on a notifications system that utilizes SignalR. We need every user to be able to "listen" to multiple groups simultaneously.

You can think of it like news alerts. A particular user may be interested in news alerts in "politics", "NBA" and "business". Every time a news alert comes into one of these categories, we want to be able to send a notification to user's browser through SignalR.

Can we simultaneously "listen" to multiple groups for every user in SignalR? If so, is there a limit to the number of groups a user can be member of at any given point?

Comment: Not that I have tested it personally - SignalR documentation states that there is no limit to the number of groups that user can join - http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups

Answer (score 0):

While there is no hardcoded limit on number of groups in SignalR but you may hit the URL size limit.  Take a look at [this](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3408#issuecomment-73934274) comment where reconnect requests were failing because the URL was too long due to the client being subscribed to too many groups.